# Adding a style sheet IE 8 with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm making a zoom button to add and remove a CSS file and for some reason I can't seem to add it in IE 8

First I tried this

```
document.createStyleSheet('style/zoom.css');
```

given that the jquery solution

```
$("head").append($("<link my style sheet />"));
```

seems to only work in FF and IE9 via my testing

I checked around the overflow and found this solution

```
 $('#zoomlink').replaceWith($('<link>', {
        id: 'zoomlink',
        href: 'style/zoom.css',
        type: 'text/css',
        rel: 'stylesheet' 
 }));
```

But still no love to be found so then frustrated i found this

```
var $link = $('&lt;link&gt;');
    $('head').add($link);
    $link.attr({
      type: 'text/css',
      href: 'style/zoom.css',
      type: 'text/css',
      rel: 'stylesheet',
      media: 'screen'
});
```

which im not certain would ever work but then finally i decided it way time to simply post a question.

I'm still not certain on how to remove the style sheet later via javascript but I need to first determine how to add a new style sheet in IE 8.

Comment: $('&lt;link&gt;') should be $('<link>')

Comment: `.add` should be `.append` also.

Comment: well now it throws an error "expected identifier" in regards to $('<link>');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will help (Sorry, can't try it in IE8):

```
(function() {
    var s  = document.createElement('link');
    s.type = 'text/css';
    s.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    s.href = 'http://yourdomain.com/style.css';
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
})();
```

Comment: To remove this stylesheet later, use document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(s);

Comment: @ert3 Please try it out in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZT6nt/.
CSS property "font-size" must increase after click on "Add" and decrease after "Remove".

Comment: @IgorShastin: Sweet how you go that to work in jsfiddle. I tried and inspecting the DOM it just would not work but did work in a normal web app. I keep a copy of that for the settings on the fiddle. +1 nice one.

Comment: i should not have jumped to conclusions you sir are a life saver

Comment: YES, document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref); fixed my IE8 error. Was using jQuery("head").append(fileref); which did not work properly. Thank you mr. @IgorShastin Any ideas why plain javascript worked indsted of jQuery here?

Answer (score 1):

To remove it I would assume a simple `remove()` would work

```
$("#zoomlink").remove();
```

To add a new link using jQuery with this syntax:

```
$("head").append(unescape("%3Clink id='zoomlink' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style/zoom.css'%3E%3C/link%3E"));
```

or using pure JavaScript

```
var e = document.createElement('link');
e.id = 'zoomlink'
e.rel = 'stylesheet';  
e.type='text/css';
r.href='style/zoom.css'
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
```

There is many other way of writing the same but the idea is the same, remove the old reference element and add a new one.

Comment: @ert3: It is hard to test in a fiddle cause fiddle places the executed code inside a frame or something but I did try that code in a proper application before. Sorry it didn't work. Maybe it is to do with the HTML or when exactly you are calling the code to remove and re-add.

Comment: i thought of that to and while you'd think that would be the situation the click function seems to work just fine